# Cannot find wlan0 wifi dongle

Tags: pi-2, wifi

I have tried multiple tutorials on how to setup wifi on my Raspberry Pi 2 but none have worked. New to Linux, hoping someone can help.

When I highlight my network connection in the toolbar I see
enxb827ebd72440:: Configured
wlx9cefd5fcb786: not associated

I have run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo reboot
```

lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
```

lsmod

```
rt2800usb              28672  0
rt2800lib             102400  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00usb              24576  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              57344  3 rt2800lib,rt2800usb,rt2x00usb
mac80211              659456  3 rt2800lib,rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb
cfg80211              573440  2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
rfkill                 28672  2 cfg80211
crc_ccitt              16384  1 rt2800lib
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet lopback
iface eth0 inet manual
allow-hotplug wlan0


auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
        wpa-ssid *****
        wpa-psk *****

wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

ifconfig

```
enxb827ebd72440: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.24  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::a12a:3903:76f5:4699  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:d7:24:40  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 407  bytes 269222 (262.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 411  bytes 59567 (58.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlx9cefd5fcb786: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 9c:ef:d5:fc:b7:86  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

wpa_supplicant

```
crtl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
ssid="****"
psk="****"
}
```

iwconfig

```
wlx9cefd5fcb786  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short  long limit:2   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

enxb827ebd72440  no wireless extensions.
```

sudo ifup wlan0

```
ifup: /etc/network/interfaces:10: unknown or no method and no inherits keyword specified
ifup: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"
```

I tried downloading the RT5370 driver but when I try to "make" it I get

sudo make

```
make -C tools
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/tools'
/home/pi/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/tools/bin2h
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/pi/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/4.14.98-v7+/build SUBDIRS=/home/pi/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.14.98-v7+'
  CC [M]  /home/pi/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data.o
/home/pi/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data.c: In function ‘RtmpPrepareHwNullFrame’:
/home/pi/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data.c:3142:34: error: passing argument 2 of ‘hex_dump’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
    hex_dump("null frame before", &longValue, 4);
                                  ^
In file included from /home/pi/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/include/rt_config.h:66:0,
                 from /home/pi/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data.c:28:
/home/pi/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/include/rt_os_util.h:679:6: note: expected ‘unsigned char *’ but argument is of type ‘UINT32 * {aka unsigned int *}’
 void hex_dump(char *str, unsigned char *pSrcBufVA, unsigned int SrcBufLen);
      ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/pi/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/include/rtmp_os.h:44:0,
                 from /home/pi/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/include/rtmp_comm.h:69,
                 from /home/pi/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/include/rt_config.h:33,
                 from /home/pi/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data.c:28:
/home/pi/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/include/os/rt_linux.h:787:29: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘RTUSBReadMACRegister’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  RTUSBReadMACRegister((_A), (_R), (PUINT32) (_pV))
                             ^
/home/pi/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data.c:3150:4: note: in expansion of macro ‘RTMP_IO_READ32’
    RTMP_IO_READ32(pAd, pAd->NullBufOffset + TXWISize+ i, &longValue);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/pi/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/include/rt_config.h:61:0,
                 from /home/pi/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data.c:28:
/home/pi/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/include/rtmp.h:7214:10: note: expected ‘USHORT {aka short unsigned int}’ but argument is of type ‘USHORT * {aka short unsigned int *}’
 NTSTATUS RTUSBReadMACRegister(
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pi/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data.c:3151:33: error: passing argument 2 of ‘hex_dump’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
    hex_dump("null frame after", &longValue, 4);
                                 ^
In file included from /home/pi/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/include/rt_config.h:66:0,
                 from /home/pi/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data.c:28:
/home/pi/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/include/rt_os_util.h:679:6: note: expected ‘unsigned char *’ but argument is of type ‘UINT32 * {aka unsigned int *}’
 void hex_dump(char *str, unsigned char *pSrcBufVA, unsigned int SrcBufLen);
      ^~~~~~~~
/home/pi/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data.c:3021:8: warning: unused variable ‘MlmeRate’ [-Wunused-variable]
  UCHAR MlmeRate;
        ^~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:326: recipe for target '/home/pi/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/pi/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data.o] Error 1
Makefile:1535: recipe for target '_module_/home/pi/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/pi/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.14.98-v7+'
Makefile:388: recipe for target 'LINUX' failed
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

Comment: Follow the steps in the tutorial, but use the correct interface name of your Wi-Fi card `wlx9cefd5fcb786` instead of `wlan0`. If you still have some problems let us know.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: You've enabled `predictable network interface names` (or is that now the default?) - disable using `raspi-config` and go to `Network Options=>Network Interface Names` and select `No` - exit out of raspi-config, reboot, and done

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but still no luck.

Comment: I have disabled predictable network interfaces and now I no longer see wlx9cefd5fcb786 in ifconfig or iwconfig and I tried changing etc/network/interfaces to use that instead of wlan0 but that completely disabled my internet connection, including wired ethernet

`auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlx9cefd5fcb786
auto wlx9cefd5fcb786

iface wlx9cefd5fcb786  inet dhcp
`

Comment: I think I am using the newest version of Raspbian

`cat /etc/issue
Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 \n \l
`

Comment: `cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.14.98-v7+ (dom@dom-XPS-13-9370) (gcc version 4.9.3 (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.22.0-88-g8460611)) #1200 SMP Tue Feb 12 20:27:48 GMT 2019
`

Comment: `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan`
shows various networks so it seems like the dongle works but my network connections still show no wireless interfaces found

Comment: In /etc/network/interfaces if I change
`iface eth0 inet manual`
to
`iface eth0 inet dhcp`
it disables all connections

Comment: I tried going into raspi-config wifi and it says "Could not communicate with wpa_supplicant" "There was an error running option N2 Wi-fi"

Comment: `iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short  long limit:2   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
`

Comment: This dongle was supposed to be plugnplay... considering just buying a raspi 3 this is so frustrating

Comment: when I open the wpa gui it says "Could not get status from wpa_supplicant"

Comment: My network uses WPA2, do I need to change something for that?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just reinstalling raspbian with the dongle plugged in, now it works great

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.